# FeathersJS login error when building for Android

Tags: android, feathersjs, jwt

I am building an Android app using Ionic. And using the following ***feathers_client.js***

```
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio-client');
const auth = require('@feathersjs/authentication-client');
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io('http://mydomain.example:3030');

const feathers_client = feathers();

feathers_client
    .configure(socketio(socket))
    .configure(auth({ storage: window.localStorage }));

module.exports = feathers_client;
```

When I run the app at the browser it works fine. But when I run it at an Android device I only get "NotAuthenticated".

I am assuming this is happening because FeathersJS stores the JWT token at window.localStorage and this is not available at the Android app userspace.

Two questions:

1) Is there any way to tell FeathersJS to store this token somewhere else?

2) If not, anyone faced this situation and may provide me a solution?

By the way, this is my code for authenticating:

```
export class SSHSettingsPage implements OnInit {

  public inputEmail: string;
  public inputPassword: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public performLogin($event) {
    let authObj: object = { "strategy": "local", "email": this.inputEmail, "password": this.inputPassword};
    client.authenticate(authObj)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      window.localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(res.user));
      window.location.href = "/download";
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      window.location.href = "/login-error";
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [configuration API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/client.html#configuration) the `storage` option can be passed an instance of the [React Native AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html):

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

// Available options are listed in the "Options" section
app.configure(auth({
  storage: AsyncStorage
}))
```